# Need help writing a better if statement with JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

Is there a better way of writing this?  Seems like the if statements could be combined somehow.

Here is the HTML

```
<header class="gray_bg" id="main_header">
```

I wrote this code to change the class name of this header tag.  It works just fine, but I feel like it could be shorter.  Any help would be great as I am still learning JS/jQuery.  Thanks!

```
$("nav#main_nav li a").on('click', function(){
    var link = $("nav#main_nav li a").index(this);
    var banner = $("header#main_header");

    if (link === 0) {
        banner.attr('class', "gray_bg");
    }

    if (link === 1) {
        banner.attr('class', "orange_bg");
    }

    if (link === 2) {
        banner.attr('class', "green_bg");
    }

    if (link === 3) {
        banner.attr('class', "purple_bg");
    }
});
```

Comment: These kinds of "multiple if statement for a single variable" work best as a [`switch statement`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp). However, the answers provided (using the number to index into an array) are great when all of your code branches are essentially parallel. Use one of the answers below, but be aware of the existence of `switch`.

Answer (score 4):

```
$("nav#main_nav li a").on('click', function(){
    var link = $("nav#main_nav li a").index(this);
    var colors = ["gray_bg", "orange_bg", "green_bg", "purple_bg"];

    $("header#main_header").attr('class', colors[link]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

just put your classes in array and just read from it with the index you got

```
var classes = ["gray_bg" ,"orange_bg","green_bg" ,"purple_bg"];
$("nav#main_nav li a").on('click', function(){
    var link = $("nav#main_nav li a").index(this);
    var banner = $("header#main_header");


    banner.attr('class', classes[link]);

});
```